# Superposition of wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, wavefunction, normalization

Suppose you have 2 normalized wavefunctions $\psi_1=Ne^{iax}e^{if(x)}e^{i\omega t}$ and  $\psi_2=Ne^{-iax}e^{if(x)}e^{i\omega t}$ defined on $x\in [-x_0,x_0]$ and vanishes for $|x|>x_0$. What then is the normalization factor for the superposed wavefunction? Perhaps an argument by the symmetry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}$ is just $2\cos \theta$.  The superposed wavefunction is

$$\Psi(x,t) = 2N\cos(ax) e^{i(f(x) + \omega t)}$$

Then

$$\Psi^*\Psi = 4N^2\cos^2(ax)$$

The average height is $2N^2$ if $x_0a = n\pi/2$, in which case $N = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1/x_0}$.  Otherwise  you can do [this integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20integrate%204%2aN%5E2%2acos%5E2%28a%2ax%29%20from%20-x0%20to%20x0%20=%201%20for%20N).

Comment: Note: f(x) is being assumed to be real value